# Can I Run a CAM simulation and a plugin simultaneously in Siemens NX?

Tags: dll, automation, cad

We have a plugin (.dll) written using SNAP for NX that captures images, running through NX open execute. The purpose of this is to capture images from the CAM simulation, but NX appear to be preventing us from executing the two at the same time. Is there a way to execute both? Can NX open and another tool run at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For potential future readers: No, you can't. The reason is, because NX is running in the main thread you can't execute a user function additional to it.

There might be a solution in some use-cases by not using SNAP and rewrite the the application in C++ or C#, then connect to NX by remote.

Comment: As you suggested, we ended up rewriting the plugin in C# and used this to call the CAM process. Thank you so much for your help!